# Pinescript Criteria based search and create alarm to send email

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I would like to search for multiple coins/shares based on my criteria and list them.

If something new pops-up according to my criteria, I would like to send an email or telegram message.

My basic idea was to compare the array size with the previous one and if the array size has changed, it means a new list for me to take action on.

Thank you in advance.

```
//@version=4
study("Searcher")

var string[] ilkListe = array.new_string(0)
string[] v1 = array.new_string(0)
var int[] prevArray = array.new_int(0)
int counter = 0

int _oldInsideABuyOrder = 0

rsiMi = rsi(close,14)

sart = rsiMi > 40

searchConditionFunc() => sart

timezone = '15'

s1 = security('CIMSA', timezone, searchConditionFunc())
s2 = security('SASA', timezone, searchConditionFunc())
s3 = security('THYAO', timezone, searchConditionFunc())
s4 = security('SISE', timezone, searchConditionFunc())

v1 := array.new_string(0)
if s1 
    array.push(v1, "CIMSA")

if s2
    array.push(v1, "SASA")

if s3
    array.push(v1, "THYAO")

if s4
    array.push(v1, "SISE")

src_label = ''
src_label := s1 ? src_label + 'CIMSA\n' : src_label
src_label := s2 ? src_label + 'SASA\n' : src_label
src_label := s3 ? src_label + 'THYAO\n' : src_label
src_label := s4 ? src_label + 'SISE\n' : src_label

l1 = label.new(bar_index, 0,src_label,color = color.green, textcolor = color.white)

_oldInsideABuyOrder := nz(array.size(v1))

plotchar(nz(array.size(v1)), title="v1ArraySize", char="", location=location.top)

plotchar(_oldInsideABuyOrder, title="_oldInsideABuyOrder", char="", location=location.top) 

plotchar(nz(array.size(prevArray)), title="prevArray", char="", location=location.top)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if s1 
    alert("CIMSA Alert", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

if s2
    alert("SASA", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

if s3
    alert("THYAO", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

if s4
    alert("SISE", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

Then, save the script, add to chart, and create the alert(s) from TradingView